# How can I show a list of resource names in a collection (a select in a form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called `Product_Categories`:

```
:string :name
:string :icon
```

I have a select in a form, which I would like to show the name of Product categories:

```
<%= builder.select :name, collection: @product_categories.each {|product_category| product_category.name} %>
```

Where @product_categories are:

```
@product_categories = Product_Category.all
```

Its not showing the names, but the whole object in the select dropdown.

How can I iterate through @product_categories to show the name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you can pass controller action `id` to use it in your business logic and `name` will be displayed to user

```
<%= builder.select :name, collection: @product_categories.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
```

Equivalent `HTML`, something like this

```
<select name="product[id]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">name1</option>
    <option value="2">name2</option>
    <option value="3">name3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` instead,

If you want to show `name` and use `name` as value

```
<%= builder.select :name, collection: @product_categories.map {|product_category| product_category.name} %>
```

If you want to show `name` and use `id` as the value, try this

```
<%= builder.select :name, collection: @product_categories.map {|product_category| [product_category.name, product_category.id]} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should be more efficient and simpler, no need to build an array then use `#each` on the array to build the options, this does the each directly on the collection

```
builder.collection_select :name, @product_categories, :id, :name
```